# Problem Downloading File From S3 Bucket using new java library

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, digital-ocean

I am using below code to download file from S3 bucket.

```
    import java.net.URI;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
    
    import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.S3ClientConfiguration;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.S3TransferManager;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.CompletedDownload;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.CompletedUpload;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.Download;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.DownloadRequest;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.FileDownload;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.Upload;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.UploadRequest;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author Codnix
     */
    public class TestDownload {
    
        public static void main(String a[]) {
    
            String bucket = "plezerjams";
    
            AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create(
                    "i am using key here",
                    "i am using my secredt key here");
    
S3AsyncClient.builder().endpointOverride(URI.create("sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com"));
            Region newRegion = Region.of("sgp1");
    
            S3TransferManager transferManager
                    = S3TransferManager.builder()
                            .s3ClientConfiguration(cfg -> cfg.credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
                            .region(newRegion).endpointOverride(URI.create("https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/"))
                            .targetThroughputInGbps(20.0)
                            .minimumPartSizeInBytes(1000l))
                            .build();
            
           
   
            FileDownload download
                    = transferManager.downloadFile(b -> b.destination(Paths.get("D:\\01.jpg"))
                    .getObjectRequest(req -> req.bucket(bucket)
                    .key("/60a34de171122c0cd4b286c3/17-06-2022/29371/01.jpg")));
    
        }
    }
```

**When i try to download file available in digital ocean spaces as above, nothing happening. Even not getting any error.**

Not sure what i am making wrong. any tips or help will solve my problem.

Comment: Are you able to download file using aws-cli?

Comment: How are you determining the key?  It's very unusual for keys in S3 storage to start with a `/`

Comment: @AnonCoward Yes  i am agree with you and i have try all other way by removing slash etc.

Comment: @mahmutoflaz yes i can download file using aws-cli and s3cmd